# Getting "Cannot add foreign key constraint" despite proper keys

Tags: mysql

I have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE `a` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `location` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `st` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`st`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I am trying to add a second table which has a foreign key referencing `st` from above:

```
CREATE TABLE b (
  id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  desc varchar(999) NOT NULL,
  var_str varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  FOREIGN KEY (var_str) REFERENCES a(st)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Every time I run the query above, I get: `Cannot add foreign key constraint`. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

The foreign key attribute has to be referring to a primary key or a column that has the UNIQUE constraint, which you should add to the `st` column:

```
`st` varchar(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
```

Comment: No, this statement is wrong. The UNIQUE constraint should be on the referenced table/column, which is `st`.

Comment: Yep, that's better!

Answer (score 0):

If I am not mistaken, in order to declare a FK constraint the referenced column must be either a Primary Key or have a UNIQUE constraint on it. So you can change the definition of table `a` to add the `UNIQUE` constraint:

```
CREATE TABLE `a` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `location` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `st` varchar(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`st`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Answer (score 0):

your primary keys is a composed (by 2 columns, `id` and `st`).

The Foreign should refer to a PK with a unique constraint or in your case add both columns.
Try:

```
FOREIGN KEY (id,var_str) REFERENCES a(id, st)
```